# how to avoid ugly composer hell of folders?

Tags: php, architecture, composer-php

... the problem is about `use` clause position and path, at my `projetc/src` folder where I run `composer require jenssegers/imagehash` now I have as `ls`:

```
composer.json  composer.lock   sync.php  
/vendor
  autoload.php  
  /composer 
  /jenssegers
       /imagehash
          composer.json  README.md  
          /src
              ImageHash.php  Implementation.php  /Implementations
```

Them, at my projects folder I run `php sync.php` ... ERROR

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error:  Class 'Jenssegers\ImageHash\ImageHash' not found**

How to fix? ... And **how to organize or install correctly all folders** with [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [*Convention over configuration*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) principles?

---

At `sync.php` I have PHP code,

```
use Jenssegers\ImageHash\ImageHash;  // after composer update
$hasher = new ImageHash;
die("\ndebug\n");
```

Comment: have you included the autoloader?

Comment: Hi @Federkun, can you show PHP code or link with it?  I used only the 2 lines "at sync.php" before die() and no "autoload" at my code... Using PHP7 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
```

to `sync.php`. You can read more about it [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

Comment: Thanks Federkun, it fixed the main problem (!), now the secondary question (expressed) is about the "tree of folders"... What you suggest as "best practice"?

Comment: what's the problem with them? it's composer's job to manage them, you shouldn't care what's inside or how the folders are organized

Comment: Hum... Perhaps is only it... but if I have a folder `myProjetc` with my code at `myProjetc/src` ... Perhaps the best practice is not to run *composer* at `myProjetc/src`, but at `myProjetc` ... is it?

Comment: You can find [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard) a very common skeleton app; you have one `vendor` folder with all your dependencies, and your source code goes into the `src` folder. You don't have a `src/vendor` folder.